# Plotting decision boundary for a neural network with two layers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network

So I've currently made a neural network with one layer (I dont know if you call that a neural network or just the perceptron). My problem is that I'm now trying to extend this for a two layer network and I would like to plot this decision boundary. I'm storing my weights for the first layer in $W$ and the weights of the second layer in $V$. The code I've been using for the perceptron is the following:

```
def plotting(classA, classB, tot_class):
    w = perceptron2(X,t,100)
    print(w)
    area = np.pi*3
    plt.scatter(classA[:,0], classA[:,1], s = area, c='b', alpha=0.5)
    plt.scatter(classB[:,0], classB[:,1],s=area, c= 'r', alpha = 0.5)
    grid = np.linspace(np.amin(tot_class),np.amax(tot_class))
    y = []
    for x in grid:
        slope = -(w[0][0] / w[0][2]) / (w[0][0] / w[0][1])
        intercept = -w[0][0] / w[0][2]
        y.append((slope*x) + intercept)
    plt.plot(grid,y, color = 'black')
    plt.show()
```

But let's be real, there wouldnt be any reason for me to implement the neural network if I expected my dataset to linearly separable, so obviously I can't use the equation for a straight line, but how do I approach this? My first thought was to plot the function where my target is 0 (i.e where it is 50 % chance that it will be qualified either -1 or +1), but is this really the way I should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to define a mesh over the area of your plot and making the perceptron predict every single value. Then you could just plot all the classA-predictions in one color and the classB-predictions in another. 
The line between the two colors is the decision boundary.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71339).

Comment: Sorry for late response, I found the answer helpful and I think I've solved it!